# Is there a way to see why a bounty was awarded?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

After browsing some posts, I noticed that some of them had completed bounties on them, and I wanted to know why a user gave a bounty. But, I was unable to figure why the bounty(s) were awarded. I know you can see the reason for a bounty that is on-going, but is there a way to see the reason for a finished one?

Comment: Revision history of the question.